# How can I tell if an HTML5 video is playing HDR content?

Tags: html5-video, hdr

Given an HTML5-based video player that plays arbitrary video files, is it possible to detect when the video is using an expanded color palette (HDR)?

Comment: No. Not unless you can check the file bytes themselves (depends if format stores such metadata).

Comment: If you can use ffmpeg in your solotion, this may help: https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/kjwxm9/how_to_detect_if_video_is_hdr_or_sdr_batch_script/